# Vuetify - Open dialog with position relative to element (eg. button)

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I am trying to position a v-dialog, with a v-card inside it, relative to a button.
This button is the activator for the dialog, and I want the dialog top left corner of the v-card to be touching the top right corner of the button when it opens - [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anc2e.png).
Currently it opens at the center of the screen.

I tried changing the position to all variables, the only result I can get is with the position: absolute and specifying top right values, I haven't been able to relate it to the button. I could settle with the position: absolute, top 8px, left 30px or whatever if it worked, but for some reason it doesn't, i have to specify a negative value for the left property, and as screen size changes it causes problems.
[this is the element structure vuetify creates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hkqW.png), the dialog is always on a div outside the main app div, no matter where I position the  tag in the code.

Thanks

Comment: What you want seems to be a v-menu with x-offset enabled and y-offset disabled. You can try the playground on the vuetify page (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/#playground)

Comment: thanks Rie, that is it